# Where to know the URL for a community page

Tags: community, community-builder

When I created a community with a template.
There are already some out-of-box pages.
Each page should have a URL to access it.

Take the `ForgotPassword` for example,
I could see the URL here is `ForgotPassword`, however I could only access it under `/login/ForgotPassword`.

I didn't see where should we configure it. Any idea?

[image: inline]

Comment: Are you saying how do you navigate to this page? By default if you are using the standard login page, you see a forgot password link there, and on clicking that link, you will be navigated to this page.

Comment: @JayantDas how could we customize the link? e.g. I want to change the URL to `/IForgotPasswd`

Comment: You can't for the ootb components. If you want to do so, that will mean you will need to create a new custom page and use identity components. Let me add details in answer if that helps.

Comment: @JayantDas I don't see identity components on the community builder. Does that mean I need to craft it by creating a custom Salesforce lightning component?

Comment: Just added that note in the answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot customize the "URL" in the standard "Forgot Password" page. If you hover around the "info" icon, you will get to see the details as below:

> The URL of the page. Editable only in custom standard pages.

[image]

---

If at all you want to customize the URL, you will need to:

1. Create a new custom page. While creating the page (or even after it has been created), you will be able to provide any custom URL that you want to use. Something as below:
   [image]
2. Utilize Identity Component "Forgot Password" to utilize the OOTB password reset functionality

However, remember you will also need to override your standard Login page for this to make sure you provide the link to your new custom page.

**Additional note**: If you don't see Identity Components in your Org, you will need to reach out to Salesforce Support to enable that. There is some permission that they enable from back-end, and only then those components start showing up in the list.